# What are the supported office UI fabric versions for SPFX 1.1.0

Tags: spfx, react, typescript, office-ui-fabric-react

There are many threads and answers regarding this question. But i didn't find a satisfying answer.

I am currently working on a SPA for SharePoint 2016 OnPrem. I scaffolded my Project with the Yeoman Generator from PNP SPFx Generator version 1.8 . So my SPFx Version is caped at 1.1.0. because that's the highest Version SP2016 OnPrem is supporting. But sadly it didn't install Fabric UI React on its own, so i don't know which Fabric Ui React Version is the highest supported one.

So i did the following steps:

- I did the workaround to get the internal microsoft gulp builder to use Typescript 2.4.2 ([Workaround for SPFx TypeScript Version](https://github.com/pnp/pnpjs/blob/6c3c37f572864a06eb37cb98c4b16d2ccb2116ce/docs-src/SPFx-On-Premesis-2016.md))
- I found someone telling that only "office-ui-fabric-react": "2.34.2" will work for my SPFx Version so i installed that (that was an old comment on another github issue i found but can't recall the url/issue).

After that i encountered an old bug in Fabric UI (a Chrome problem with drag&drop) so i went on to find a solution to upgrade Fabric UI.

Now i got it pumped up to:

```
{
  "name": "timeplan",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=0.10.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "gulp bundle",
    "clean": "gulp clean",
    "test": "gulp test",
    "preversion": "node ./tools/pre-version.js",
    "postversion": "gulp dist"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@microsoft/sp-core-library": "~1.1.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset": "~1.1.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-office-ui-fabric-core": "~1.4.0-0",
    "@microsoft/sp-webpart-base": "~1.1.0",
    "@pnp/common": "^1.3.6",
    "@pnp/logging": "^1.3.6",
    "@pnp/odata": "^1.3.6",
    "@pnp/pnpjs": "^1.3.5",
    "@pnp/sp": "^1.3.6",
    "@types/es6-promise": "0.0.33",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.12",
    "@types/webpack-env": "1.13.1",
    "office-ui-fabric-react": "5.135.3",
    "react": "15.4.2",
    "react-dom": "15.4.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "@types/react": "15.0.29"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@microsoft/sp-build-web": "~1.1.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-module-interfaces": "~1.1.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-webpart-workbench": "~1.1.0",
    "@types/chai": "3.4.34",
    "@types/mocha": "2.2.38",
    "ajv": "~5.2.2",
    "gulp": "~3.9.1",
    "gulp-sequence": "1.0.0",
    "typescript": "^2.4.2"
  }
}
```

My gulp task builds and even serves it. But i got sometimes strange Type mismatches regarding JSX in the Render function of my code.

Does someone know the golden Rule for the versions for SPFx(1.1.0) + Fabric UI + React + Typescript(2.4.2) ?
Whats the highest i can go with this setup ?

Comment: Did you ever figure out an answer to this?  I'm stuck on SP2016/SPFx 1.1 also, and after not being able to find a compatible version of Fabric UI React, I resorted to using Semantic UI React 0.81.0, since I had some previous experience with Semantic UI React.  Would like to move over to an MS UI framework though, to keep it "in the family."